# XML transform not behaving as expected. Do I need a loop?

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt

I have XML data from my website in the form of orders for a given time period.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WEB_ORDERS>
  <WEB_ORDER>
    <ORDER>
      <ORDER_ID>1234</ORDER_ID>
      <ORDER_REFERENCE>WEB3395</ORDER_REFERENCE>
      <DELIVERY_METHOD>UPS Access Point (FREE) (pay by card only)</DELIVERY_METHOD>
      <GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_INC>0</GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_INC>
      <GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_NET>0</GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_NET>
      <GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_VAT>0</GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_VAT>
      <NUMBER_PRODUCTS>1</NUMBER_PRODUCTS>
    </ORDER>
    <CUSTOMER>
      <CUSTOMER_ID>3392</CUSTOMER_ID>
      <BILLING_COMPANY_NAME></BILLING_COMPANY_NAME>
      <BILLING_TITLE>MR</BILLING_TITLE>
      <BILLING_FIRSTNAME>C3</BILLING_FIRSTNAME>
      <BILLING_LASTNAME>PO</BILLING_LASTNAME>
      <Customer_Data>data here</Customer_Data>
    </CUSTOMER>
  </WEB_ORDER>
  <WEB_ORDER>
    <ORDER>
      <ORDER_ID>3396</ORDER_ID>
      <ORDER_REFERENCE>WEB3396</ORDER_REFERENCE>
      <DELIVERY_METHOD>UPS Access Point (FREE) (pay by card only)</DELIVERY_METHOD>
      <GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_INC>0</GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_INC>
      <GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_NET>0</GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_NET>
      <GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_VAT>0</GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_VAT>
      <NUMBER_PRODUCTS>2</NUMBER_PRODUCTS>
    </ORDER>
    <CUSTOMER>
      <CUSTOMER_ID>2584</CUSTOMER_ID>
      <BILLING_COMPANY_NAME></BILLING_COMPANY_NAME>
      <BILLING_TITLE>MR</BILLING_TITLE>
      <BILLING_FIRSTNAME>R2</BILLING_FIRSTNAME>
      <BILLING_LASTNAME>D2</BILLING_LASTNAME>
      <Customer_Data>data here</Customer_Data>
    </CUSTOMER>
  </WEB_ORDER>

</WEB_ORDERS>
```

Upon importing this data into access the data is split into it's child nodes and thus I get many tables. This is fine apart from there is no link between some of the tables.

order contains to no link to customer for example. So I learnt about XSLT's.
and went about writing one to insert CUSTOMER_ID into `<ORDERS>`. It works perfectly for files with a single order in. but some file like the XML above have more than one order in them so it will only copy the original customer number (1234 in this case) and apply that to all the orders. I am really not certain how to loop though each `<WEB_ORDER>` do my transform and then loop onto the next `<WEB_ORDER>`

Here is my working XSLT for single order files.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <WEB_ORDER>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </WEB_ORDER>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="WEB_ORDER">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ORDER">
        <ORDER>
            <CUSTOMER_ID><xsl:value-of select="/WEB_ORDERS/WEB_ORDER/CUSTOMER/CUSTOMER_ID"/></CUSTOMER_ID>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </ORDER>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So when I run this transform on my XML I would get this with the first web_order customer ID repeated in each order

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <WEB_ORDERS>
      <WEB_ORDER>
        <ORDER>
          <CUSTOMER_ID>3392</CUSTOMER_ID>
          <ORDER_ID>1234</ORDER_ID>
          <ORDER_REFERENCE>WEB3395</ORDER_REFERENCE>
          <DELIVERY_METHOD>UPS Access Point (FREE) (pay by card only)</DELIVERY_METHOD>
          <GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_INC>0</GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_INC>
          <GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_NET>0</GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_NET>
          <GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_VAT>0</GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_VAT>
          <NUMBER_PRODUCTS>1</NUMBER_PRODUCTS>
        </ORDER>
        <CUSTOMER>
          <CUSTOMER_ID>3392</CUSTOMER_ID>
          <BILLING_COMPANY_NAME></BILLING_COMPANY_NAME>
          <BILLING_TITLE>MR</BILLING_TITLE>
          <BILLING_FIRSTNAME>C3</BILLING_FIRSTNAME>
          <BILLING_LASTNAME>PO</BILLING_LASTNAME>
          <Customer_Data>data here</Customer_Data>
        </CUSTOMER>
      </WEB_ORDER>
      <WEB_ORDER>
        <ORDER>
          <CUSTOMER_ID>3392</CUSTOMER_ID>
          <ORDER_ID>3396</ORDER_ID>
          <ORDER_REFERENCE>WEB3396</ORDER_REFERENCE>
          <DELIVERY_METHOD>UPS Access Point (FREE) (pay by card only)</DELIVERY_METHOD>
          <GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_INC>0</GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_INC>
          <GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_NET>0</GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_NET>
          <GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_VAT>0</GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_VAT>
          <NUMBER_PRODUCTS>2</NUMBER_PRODUCTS>
        </ORDER>
        <CUSTOMER>
          <CUSTOMER_ID>2584</CUSTOMER_ID>
          <BILLING_COMPANY_NAME></BILLING_COMPANY_NAME>
          <BILLING_TITLE>MR</BILLING_TITLE>
          <BILLING_FIRSTNAME>R2</BILLING_FIRSTNAME>
          <BILLING_LASTNAME>D2</BILLING_LASTNAME>
          <Customer_Data>data here</Customer_Data>
        </CUSTOMER>
      </WEB_ORDER>

    </WEB_ORDERS>
```

What I am trying to get is this with the customer id for the web_order in the order node

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WEB_ORDERS>
  <WEB_ORDER>
    <ORDER>
      <CUSTOMER_ID>3392</CUSTOMER_ID>
      <ORDER_ID>1234</ORDER_ID>
      <ORDER_REFERENCE>WEB3395</ORDER_REFERENCE>
      <DELIVERY_METHOD>UPS Access Point (FREE) (pay by card only)</DELIVERY_METHOD>
      <GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_INC>0</GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_INC>
      <GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_NET>0</GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_NET>
      <GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_VAT>0</GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_VAT>
      <NUMBER_PRODUCTS>1</NUMBER_PRODUCTS>
    </ORDER>
    <CUSTOMER>
      <CUSTOMER_ID>3392</CUSTOMER_ID>
      <BILLING_COMPANY_NAME></BILLING_COMPANY_NAME>
      <BILLING_TITLE>MR</BILLING_TITLE>
      <BILLING_FIRSTNAME>C3</BILLING_FIRSTNAME>
      <BILLING_LASTNAME>PO</BILLING_LASTNAME>
      <Customer_Data>data here</Customer_Data>
    </CUSTOMER>
  </WEB_ORDER>
  <WEB_ORDER>
    <ORDER>
      <CUSTOMER_ID>2584</CUSTOMER_ID>
      <ORDER_ID>3396</ORDER_ID>
      <ORDER_REFERENCE>WEB3396</ORDER_REFERENCE>
      <DELIVERY_METHOD>UPS Access Point (FREE) (pay by card only)</DELIVERY_METHOD>
      <GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_INC>0</GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_INC>
      <GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_NET>0</GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_NET>
      <GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_VAT>0</GIFTWRAP_TOTAL_VAT>
      <NUMBER_PRODUCTS>2</NUMBER_PRODUCTS>
    </ORDER>
    <CUSTOMER>
      <CUSTOMER_ID>2584</CUSTOMER_ID>
      <BILLING_COMPANY_NAME></BILLING_COMPANY_NAME>
      <BILLING_TITLE>MR</BILLING_TITLE>
      <BILLING_FIRSTNAME>R2</BILLING_FIRSTNAME>
      <BILLING_LASTNAME>D2</BILLING_LASTNAME>
      <Customer_Data>data here</Customer_Data>
    </CUSTOMER>
  </WEB_ORDER>

</WEB_ORDERS>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line, as it gets the first `CUSTOMER_ID` node in the XML regardless of what `ORDER` you are on.

```
<xsl:value-of select="/WEB_ORDERS/WEB_ORDER/CUSTOMER/CUSTOMER_ID"/>
```

You need to change it to this, so that it gets the `CUSTOMER` node for the same parent of the current `ORDER` node. (`..` gets the parent node of the current node).

```
<xsl:value-of select="../CUSTOMER/CUSTOMER_ID"/>
```

Try this template in place of the current one

```
<xsl:template match="ORDER">
    <ORDER>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <CUSTOMER_ID><xsl:value-of select="../CUSTOMER/CUSTOMER_ID"/></CUSTOMER_ID>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </ORDER>
</xsl:template>
```

Note how I have split up the select of `@*` and `node()` because attributes must be added to the parent element before any child nodes are.

But in answer to your question, no, you don't need a loop. Your template approach is very much the way to go.

Comment: Tim, thank you very much. that has exactly created what I want and now I see it laid out I believe I understand it much better.